# Omitting the return type in abstract method, but not in abstract field

Tags: scala

For example i have the following trait:

```
trait Some {
  def method // i can omit the return type
  val field: Some  // i can't 
}
```

If i omit the type of an abstract field it will raise a compile error, but not in case of a method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's drop-dead simple. If you omit the return type of an abstract method, 
then Scala compiler will infer it as a `Unit` (after typer phase):

```
abstract trait Some extends scala.AnyRef {
  def method: Unit;
  <stable> <accessor> def field: String
}
```